# OpenGL - Going 3D

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, sdl, glm-math

I have a script that I am unable to make fully 3D. So far on ortho the background shows up only. In perspective, almost nothing shows up but when I move the camera it does change color.

```
projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(44.0f), static_cast<GLfloat>(Width) / static_cast<GLfloat>(Height), 0.1f, 100.0f);
projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<GLfloat>(Width), static_cast<GLfloat>(Height), 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

See below for images:

Image 1:
3D version - Ortho
[image: 3D version - Unstable]

Image 2:
3D version - Ortho
[image: 3D version - Unstable]

Image 3:
2D version - Stable and works perfectly
[image: 2D version - Stable and works perfectly]

Here is my code that creates and renders sprites:

```
#ifndef SPRITE_H
#define SPRITE_H

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

#include "ShaderClass.h"
#include "TextureClass.h"


class Sprite
{
public:
    Shader shader;
    // Set up Vertex Array Object && Vertex Buffer Object
    GLuint  VAO, 
            VBO;

    // Constructor
    Sprite(Shader &shader){ this->shader = shader; setBuffers(); }
    // Deconstructor
    ~Sprite(){ glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO); }

    // Initializes and configures the buffers and vertex attributes
    void setBuffers()
    {
        // Define vertices for the sprite
        GLfloat vertices[] = {
            //  x     y     z      u     v
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

            0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

            0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

            0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f
        };

        //
        // OpenGL buffers
        // Initialization code using Vertex Array Object (VAO) (done once (unless the object frequently changes))
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
        // Copy our vertices array in a buffer for OpenGL to use
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        // Bind Vertex Array Object
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        //Attributes
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);       // location = 0 
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                             // location = 0
            3,                             // 3 components (x, y, z)
            GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
            5 * sizeof(GLfloat),           // stride: 5 * float (x, y, z, u, v)
            (GLvoid*)0);                   // offset: 0

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);       // location = 1 
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            1,                             // location = 1
            2,                             // 2 components (u, v)
            GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
            5 * sizeof(GLfloat),           // stride: 5 * float (x, y, z, u, v)
            (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat))); // offset: 3 * float (x, y, z)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        //Unbind the VAO
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    // Renders the sprite
    void DrawSprite(Texture &texture, glm::vec2 position, glm::vec2 size = glm::vec2(10, 10), GLfloat rotate = 0.0f, glm::vec3 colour = glm::vec3(1.0f))
    {
        // Apply the shader
        this->shader.Use();

        // Transform the object
        glm::mat4   transformObject;
                    transformObject = glm::translate(transformObject, glm::vec3(position, 0.0f));
                    transformObject = glm::translate(transformObject, glm::vec3(0.5f * size.x, 0.5f * size.y, 0.0f));
                    transformObject = glm::rotate(transformObject, rotate, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
                    transformObject = glm::translate(transformObject, glm::vec3(-0.5f * size.x, -0.5f * size.y, 0.0f));
                    transformObject = glm::scale(transformObject, glm::vec3(size, 1.0f));

        this->shader.SetVector3f("spriteColour", colour);
        this->shader.SetMatrix4("transformObject", transformObject);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        // Bind the appropriate texture to *this* model
        texture.Bind();

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36 * 5);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
};

#endif
```

These are the shaders that I am using:

Vertex shader:

```
#version 440 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 transformObject;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    TexCoords = vec2(texCoord.x, texCoord.y);
    gl_Position = projection * view * transformObject * vec4(Position.x, Position.y, Position.z, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 440 core
in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 colour;

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform vec3 spriteColour;

void main()
{    
    colour = vec4(spriteColour, 1.0) * texture(tex, TexCoords);
}
```

Comment: A comment is that all the `this->SomeName` indirections are not needed. When you're in the scope of the object all member variables and functions can be accessed directly. `this->VAO` can be written just `VAO`.

Comment: One thing I find odd is you are sending vertices and uvs interleaved then you have to pass glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36 * 5 ); .  pass 36 * 5 . Also one more tip top debug is just try out putting texColour and spriteColour.

Comment: glm's default matrix constructor will initialize to all zeros, as a result, `transformMat` is going to be still all zeros after all those other transforms are multiplied to it, which will give very interesting effects as this even sets `w` to 0.

Comment: Updated, a lot of the code has changed, the problem still remains that 3D isn't fully working.